# sql server query to add value to existing value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with few columns, one of these columns called _bandwidth and the value inside it is decimal.

So i wanna type a sql query that adds values to existing value.

Say the value of _bandwidth of user id 1 is 150.000 and i wanna add 200 to this value so sum would be 350.000

This is the query i typed but it didin't work.

```
update users set _bandwidth = (select _bandiwdth from users where _ID = 1) + 150 where _ID = 1
```

Also did something like:

```
update users set _bandwidth += 200 where _ID = 1
```

Of course they are wrong, but i hope you understand what i wanna achieve.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT**
Found the solution and the answer would be:

```
update users set _bandwidth = _bandwidth + 200 where _ID = 1
```

Comment: += 200 would work on SQL Server 2008 and above. That syntax is not possible in 2005 or lower. Very useful to specify the version (via a tag) and also to *not* tag SQL Server questions with MySQL for some reason.

Comment: Yeah i have SQL server 2005 installed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
UPDATE Users
SET _bandwidth = _bandwidth + 200
WHERE _ID =1
```

would work

Answer (score 7):

```
update users 
set _bandwidth = _bandiwdth + 200
where _ID = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update users 
set _bandwidth = _bandwidth + 200 
where _ID = 1
```